# Why does the d3 force layout seem to crash and how should I overcome it?

Tags: angularjs, d3.js

I was playing around with a force layout and when I drag an item aggressively around it seems to eventually cause things to freeze.

So the questions are,

1. Why does this happen?
2. Is there a way to catch this and restart it?

[Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/dZMMw8pICFuSA7SW3W6r?p=preview)

```
$scope.render = function() {
 _this.changeForce();
 var circles = $scope.svg
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(items)
 circles.exit().remove();
 circles.enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", function(d) {
    return d.radius;
  })
  .attr("fill", "blue")
  .call(d3.behavior.drag()
    .origin(function(d) { return d; })
    .on("drag", function(d) {
      d.x = d3.event.x, d.y = d3.event.y;
      d3.select(this).attr("cx", d.x).attr("cy", d.y);
    }))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On drag you are missing a call to make the force layout "tick" again:

```
.call(d3.behavior.drag()
  .origin(function(d) { return d; })
  .on("drag", function(d) {
    d.x = d3.event.x, d.y = d3.event.y;
    d3.select(this).attr("cx", d.x).attr("cy", d.y);
    _this.force.resume(); //<-- get it moving again
   })
)
```

Updated [code](http://plnkr.co/edit/dZieY4dsptu5CJ5AUAyc?p=preview).